# PHP/PEAR Mail Not Sending as Text Message

Tags: php, email, smtp, pear

I'm working on a script that will send text messages via email (i.e. ###@txt.att.net) and PHP's simple mail() function was not working. I could send email messages just fine through that method, but the texts were not being delivered. I did more research and found that carriers often block messages without a sender and using PEAR with SMTP is a better solution.

However, the following code works to send emails but is still not delivering AT&T text messages:

```
<?php
require_once "Mail.php";

$from = "XXX <XXX>";
$to = "XXX <XXX@txt.att.net>";
$subject = "Test email using PHP SMTP\r\n\r\n";
$body = "This is a test email message";

$host = "XXX";
$port = "26";
$username = "XXX";
$password = "XXX";

$headers = array (
'From' => $from,
'To' => $to,
'Subject' => $subject);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
array (
'host' => $host,
'port' => $port,
'auth' => true,
'username' => $username,
'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
  echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
  echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
}

?>
```

Is it maybe an issue with headers not being formatted correctly, etc? Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, mail in cPanel told me to use 26 and it seems to send mail fine with either one. In fact, I can totally omit the port and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to their example you do not need the new lines after the subject:

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.send.php

Check the AT&T response they might decline it if they have you blacklisted or you do not have a valid rDNS or other reasons.

They seem to experience a problem seeing the rDNS records of some IP's.

Use this it will tell you all the info you need.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/xmail-the-right-way

Post the log of it here.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it without the line breaks (and with a blank subject) but no luck... What constitutes a valid rDNS? When I lookup my current site, it does show another domain (one of my others) as the top level domain. Is that a problem?

Comment: Not as long as it is valid. Did you look at the example from the pear site?

Comment: Yes I have tried that example and it doesn't work for me at all... not even to a regular email address.

Comment: Try this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/xmail-the-right-way/ It should not be to difficult for you to take out the WP part and use just the main class.

Comment: Your code looks ok. If you're email can be delivered to an account over the internet (gmail, yahoo, whatever is outside of your own network), then you are being filtered as spam. DNS issues, or bad mailing reputation from your IP could be the issue. Have you tried SMTP over telnet from your mail server ip to AT&T?

Comment: He needs to record the response code from AT&T that would tell him what exactly the problem is.

Comment: A response code from an email? How would I go about recording that? Any suggestions?

Comment: The Xmail script can do that. It connects directly to the destination MX server and logs all exchanged commands and status. I have built SMTP servers so trust me on this. Xmail is a basic PHP class I built to diagnose and fix someone's similar problem.

Comment: Okay, I'll give xmail a try (first on a WP site) and then try to tear it apart to work outside of WP if it sends messages correctly. Thanks!

Comment: It works 99.9% there are a few exceptions of email systems very old that might not accept the EHLO. Change it in HELO in that case. I did not build it to be used as a highly complex email delivery system. I built it to do general delivery and mainly to be able to record logs for diagnosis.